# How to run a blinking text code in background

Tags: powershell

I found a code on internet ,working code of  a function to blink a text. I am using the function in my pwershell application . But I want the blinking code to run in background.
The function is

```
$function = {
function Blink-Message {
 param([String]$Message,[int]$Delay,[int]$Count,[ConsoleColor[]]$Colors) 
    $startColor = [Console]::ForegroundColor
    $startLeft  = [Console]::CursorLeft
    $startTop   = [Console]::CursorTop
    $colorCount = $Colors.Length

    $line = "$message"
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $Count; $i++) {
        [Console]::CursorLeft = $startLeft
        [Console]::CursorTop  = $startTop
        [Console]::ForegroundColor = $Colors[$($i % $colorCount)]
        [Console]::WriteLine($Message)
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $Delay


    }
    [Console]::ForegroundColor = $startColor
}
}

# Set-Alias blink Blink-Message

#write-host -NoNewline "hello  "; Blink-Message "blink" 1000 15 "red,black" | Receive-Job 
write-host -NoNewline "hello1  "; start-job -InitializationScript $function -ScriptBlock {Blink-Message} -InputObject "blink1",1000,15,"red,black" | Receive-Job
write-host -NoNewline "hello2  "; start-job -InitializationScript $function -ScriptBlock {Blink-Message} -InputObject "blink2",1000,15,"red,black" | Receive-Job  
write-host -NoNewline "hello3  "; start-job -InitializationScript $function -ScriptBlock {Blink-Message} -InputObject "blink3",1000,15,"red,black" | Receive-Job
```

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work ok. Better than I thought it would (there are essentially two threads writing to the console at the same time and they aren't synchronized which is usually a recipe for unpredictable behavior).

I added $x and $y parameters. $x is what column you want the blinking message to be in. $y is the number of rows above the row where the prompt currently is. It looks best if you make $y one less than `$host.ui.rowui.windowsize.height` The flashing message is at the top of the screen if you do. Otherwise the flashing message will end up on multiple lines whenever the console scrolls. Note this script is only tested on POWERSHELL.EXE. It definitely will not work on powershell_ise.

While writing this, I crashed/hung powershell a number of times. Each time you run the script it creates a job which will remain in the "running" state (even after all the repetitions specified by $count have completed). Having multiple jobs running in the background, potentially all writing to the screen is probably something you want to avoid. The `jobless` function will remove all jobs.

```
function Blink-Message {
 param([String]$Message,[int]$Delay,[int]$Count,[ConsoleColor[]]$Colors,$x=0,$y=0) 
    $script:colorCount = $Colors.Length
    $script:theColors = $colors
    $script:theCount = $count
    $script:msg = $Message
    $script:col = $x
    $script:deltarow = $y
    $tmr = new-object timers.timer $Delay
    $tmr.AutoReset = $true
    $tmr.Enabled = $true
    $script:cnt = 0

    $null = Register-ObjectEvent $tmr -EventName Elapsed -Action {
        param( $sender)

        $curColor = [Console]::ForegroundColor
        $curLeft  = [Console]::CursorLeft
        $curTop   = [Console]::CursorTop
        [Console]::CursorLeft  = $col
        if ([Console]::CursorTop -lt -$deltarow) {
          [Console]::CursorTop  = 0
        } else {
          [Console]::CursorTop  += $deltarow
        }

        [Console]::ForegroundColor = $theColors[$($cnt % $colorCount)]
        [Console]::WriteLine($msg)
        [Console]::CursorLeft = $curLeft
        [Console]::CursorTop  = $curTop
        [Console]::ForegroundColor = $curColor
        if ($script:cnt++ -ge $theCount) {
          try {$sender.Enabled=$false} catch{wh send catch}
        }
    }
}


Set-Alias blink Blink-Message

blink "$("="*30) gabby foo" 100 100 "green","black","yellow","darkblue" 0 -79

#
# Use jobless to kill all jobs
function jobless { get-job;get-job|Stop-Job -pass | Remove-Job}
```